# sudo apt-get upgrade results in 404 errors for everything

Tags: apt, 18.04, upgrade, updates

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and I'm trying to update things on my system. I've tried running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Which produces a few 404 errors:

```
sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                           
Hit:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                   
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                          
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic InRelease                    
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]                                                  
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                                          
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                             
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                             
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages [1,007 kB]                                      
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [295 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages [212 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Ign:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Ign:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Ign:49 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB] 
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB] 
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]
Ign:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages
Ign:78 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:79 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:80 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages      
Ign:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:81 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse arm64 Packages    
Ign:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:82 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:83 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:49 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:84 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:85 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:78 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages  
Ign:79 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:80 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:81 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:82 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:83 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:49 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:84 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:85 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:78 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages  
Ign:79 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted arm64 Packages
Err:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Ign:80 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:81 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:82 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:49 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:83 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:84 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:78 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:85 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Err:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Ign:79 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:80 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:81 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse arm64 Packages
Err:82 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Ign:83 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:84 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:85 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Fetched 419 kB in 4s (104 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Then sudo apt-get upgrade seems to think nothing exists:

```
tombot@Magma-Core-Kernel:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Also --fix-missing doesn't help. I've tried upgrading the distro with

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But this gives the same result as "sudo apt-get upgrade"

I'm able to ping 91.189.91.26 just fine:

```
ping 91.189.91.26
PING 91.189.91.26 (91.189.91.26) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 91.189.91.26: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=79.6 ms
```

I tried downloading a new sources.list file, but I still get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Also, this is my first StackExchange post, so I hope I've done everything right with my post..

Thanks!

Comment: Have you modified `/etc/apt/sources.list`, or added any .list files into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`?

Comment: Yes, I tried modifying sources.list as Philippe Delteil suggested.

Comment: It looks like you modified more that just what philippe suggested, yes? Did you make a backup of sources.list before you made any changes?

Comment: ...No ...oops. Those errors are from before I made the changes though.

Comment: Had you made changes to sources.list BEFORE philippe's changes? What kind of processor do you have, arm64? amd64? No backup of sources.list, correct?

Comment: It's a regular old 64-bit Dell laptop, so amd64, I believe. I don't think I modified sources.list before, but it's possible I did. I just backed-up sources.list and created a brand new one using Software Updater. Still similar issues with Software Updater reporting "Failed to download repository information. Check your internet connection."

Comment: Show me the current output showing the errors.

Comment: I've edited the original post to show the new errors from apt-get update. Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: I don't understand where the binary-arm64 references are coming from. You just installed a new /etc/apt/sources.list file, yes? `grep -i arm64 /etc/apt/sources.list` and `grep -i arm64 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`. Report back.

Comment: grep produces no hits in either case. I did do some arm64 development for a Jetson TX2 board last term, and it's possible my attempts to install JetPack 3.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 when it's meant to be installed on Ubuntu 16.04 caused some issues.

Comment: OK, show me `ls -al /etc/apt` and `ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d`. They may be kind of long, so you may wish to use imgur.com to post them. Just give me the links here.

Comment: If you need to uninstall JetPack, here's something that should help... https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1020469/jetson-tx2/how-to-remove-jetpack-3-0-on-tx2-/

Comment: Here you go: https://imgur.com/a/65A5scy. On another note, it seems JetPack components are no longer installed..

Comment: Do Update #1 in my answer. Report back. We're looking for the arm64 references.

Comment: sometimes such errors are due to package distribution propagation delay issues which fix themselves by just waiting a new minutes for that sync to complete then reissue ... YMMV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer...

From the comments...

The user is having problems updating their software repositories.

`/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` files have been modified. They have references to a non-existent arm64 repo.

`/etc/apt/sources.list` has been replaced with a standard 18.04 version. The errors are decreased.

We're searching `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` files for "binary-arm64" errors now.

**Update #1:**

The new `/etc/apt/sources.list` has some wrong stuff. Do these to fix it...

`sudo chown root:root /etc/apt/sources.list`

`sudo chmod 644 /etc/apt/sources.list`

Then lets do a gross search for arm64...

`sudo grep -r arm64 /etc/apt`

**Update #2:**

Ubuntu was reinstalled, and everything is working fine again, including Virtualbox.

Comment: Somehow... still no results from grep.

Comment: @TomBot Well, we've gotten rid of most of your errors, but these last 4 have me stumped. Somewhere it's finding "binary-arm64", but it's not in the normal places. So who knows where it's hiding. You might just have to reinstall Ubuntu to undo all of the changes in your system.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking of just reinstalling Ubuntu. Thanks for all the help! Should I change the status of this post somehow?

Comment: @TomBot lets wait until after you've reinstalled and got it working, then I'll update my answer.

Comment: A fresh install did the trick. Everything is working now. I'm able to install VirtualBox now, which is what I intended to do in the first place.. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

The problem you're facing is basically a problem to reach the IP 91.189.91.26, try restarting your Internet connection and check if you can ping the IP address using this command:

```
ping 91.189.91.26
```

In my case it works correctly.

If nothing works for you, try changing the mirror you're using to get the updates:

Open your sources.list file using your favorite text editor, in my case nano.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Locate the text

> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

and replace it with

> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

And then run:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

If it still doesn't work, you might try a distribution update:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If still not working, this is what I've found [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-fix-ubuntu-debian-apt-get-404-not-found-repository-errors)

> Run the following command to update archive.ubuntu.com and
> security.ubuntu.com package repository URLs with
> old-releases.ubuntu.com. Since the normal Ubuntu releases link to the
> archive.XXX and security.XX URLs, the support will be removed after
> their live cycle of 9 months and respective repositories moved to
> old-releases.….

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Good luck.

Comment: I was able to ping 91.189.91.26 just fine. I changed the mirror as you suggested, but I'm still producing 404 errors.

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: I would like to upgrade from 18.04.1 to 18.04.2 to fix these problems, but that's not working because my repository is old? Seems like a catch 22, or rather, a catch 404 in this case.

Comment: The last solution is your only chance by now.

Comment: Sorry, I get:

Err:2 http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
  Could not resolve 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com'

E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: it should be http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

Comment: I removed the "us." is that what you meant? It still produces errors.

Comment: Try replacing your /etc/apt/sources.list with this one https://gist.github.com/h0bbel/4b28ede18d65c3527b11b12fa36aa8d1

Comment: It works for me: 
`sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: @PhilippeDelteil THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Replace `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` with `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

A slightly different solution; If this is happening when you build a docker Dockerfile with Ubuntu, using a command similar to `docker build -t "localhost:5000/blahblah" .` then it's due to the `sources.list` being cached and being obsolete. To fix this, use the `no-cache` switch, like so `docker build --no-cache -t "localhost:5000/blahblah" .`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't installed a ladder, so I met the 404,too.
After I deselected checkboxes which is before 'http://us...' in 'Software & Updates' > 'Other Software', click button 'close' then 'reload', I could use
`sudo apt-get update` with no error